# Adding custom UIView class to custom UICollectionViewCell have different results

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionviewcell, uibezierpath

This may not be the best implementation, so I am open to other suggestions.

I want to create a `UICollectionView` that has a custom `UIView` that draws a circle (similar to the Watch's Activity circle. The issue I am experiencing is that in every `cell` after the first ones that are presented (having to scroll) the circle is drawn in the top left circle instead of being centered, the wrong size, and I'm not sure what I need to change.

`UIView` class

```
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        
        var path = UIBezierPath()
        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: self.center, radius: (self.frame.height / 2)-10, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: (2 * CGFloat.pi - CGFloat.pi / 2), clockwise: true)
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        
        
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 6
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
    
    func setProgress(progress: NSNumber) {
        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

        basicAnimation.toValue = progress

        basicAnimation.duration = 1

        basicAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "setProgress")
    }
    
    func setColor(color: UIColor) {
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
    }
```

`UICollectionViewCell`

```
@IBOutlet weak var view: CustomViewClass!

var key: String!
```

I connect `CustomViewClass` to a UIView using the storyboard.

Comment: So if you added that view to the cell in the storyboard, this is where the issue is. What constraints have you specified?

Comment: I've specified that the custom view had a leading, trailing, top, and bottom of 0. The size of the cell is always correct. Do you recommend programmatic constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're drawing the circle in `override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {` which is called once when the view is created or appear. At that moment the frame (origin, size) wasn't calculated by autolayout yet.

You need to re-draw the circle again when setup your cell in `cell for row atIndex`.

Comment: I knew it was silly - fixed it with `setNeedsDisplay()`. Thank you!!